# Get between times only

Tags: mysql

I need just the times from a unix timestamp date column between midnight and 6 in the morning

I tried this

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE TIME_FORMAT(`dateColumn`, '%H:%i') BETWEEN '00:01' AND '06:00';
```

No results...

Comment: What is the type of `dateColumn`? If it's a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, the formatting is unnecessary.

Comment: maybe you should use  FROM_UNIXTIME to convert to a date format

Comment: it's an INT with datetime in seconds

Comment: can you give example of your column datecolumn ?

Comment: If it's an `INT`, the following might work: `...WHERE dateColumn BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-02-14 00:00:00") AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP("2014-02-14 06:00:00")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your datecolumn values

```
SELECT * FROM table  WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME (`dateColumn`, '%H:%i') BETWEEN '12:01' AND '12:50';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE TIME_FORMAT(`dateColumn`, '%H:%i') BETWEEN
CAST('00:00:01' AS time) AND end > CAST('06:00:00' AS time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same query worked for me...

In your case convert UnixTimeStamp to Date...

STR_TO_DATE(UnixDateTime, '%M %d,%Y %H:%i:%s.%f') then apply same query